# Ordenar tabla HTML por columnas sin que esta sea responsive

Tags: html, table

Estoy tratando de hacer que los datos que introduzco dentro de una tabla `HTML` mediante `php` me aparezcan ordenados por defecto por las columnas que yo quiera que tengan preferencia a la hora de ser ordenadas.

El método que utilizo a la hora de rellenar la tabla sería el siguiente:

```
<table id="miTabla">
    <tr>    
        <td>Color</td>
        <td>Talla</td>
        <td>Almacen</td>
        <td>Stock</td>
        <td>Transito</td>
    </tr>

    <?php for($i = 0; $i < $codArtRes->tNumReg ; $i++){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $codArtRes->tColor[$i]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $codArtRes->tTalla[$i]; ?>   </td>
        <td><?php echo$codArtRes->tAlmacen[$i]; ?>  </td>
        <td><?php echo $codArtRes->tStock[$i]; ?>   </td>
        <td><?php echo $codArtRes->tTransito[$i]; ?>    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>

</table>
```

Lo que hago en el código anterior es recuperar los datos en cuestión accediendo a las variables con las que cuenta `$CodArtRes` (**tColor, tTalla, tAlmacen, tStock, tTransito**) las cuales son `array`, para ello hago uso de la variable `tNumReg` que es un contador del número de registros que recibo, utilizándola para crear un `for` que me recorra todos los registros y me cree una fila diferente con los datos pertinentes.

Lo que busco conseguir es que por defecto, cuando esta tabla se cargue los datos me vengan ya ordenados, en este caso primero por la columna referente a color y después por la de talla.

He visto ya algunas soluciones que involucran `jQuery`, pero son soluciones que van enfocadas a conseguir que la tabla sea `responsive`, cosa que yo no busco. Únicamente busco el ordenar sus datos desde el inicio, desde el momento en el que se muestra la tabla.

Comment: Dónde tienes almacenados los datos? SQL, MySQL?. Si haces una consulta, puedes usar la cláuslula `order by`, así los datos se mostrarán en el orden que indiques en la consulta. Por ejemplo: `SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY campo1 ASC, campo2 ASC;`.

Comment: En mi caso se trataba de una base de datos de Progress ABL, pero si, efectivamente era llevar a cabo la ordenación desde la misma consulta. Gracias!